# Problema com pontuação e espaço ao executar CMD via C#

Tags: c#, mysql, cmd, mysqldump

Tenho um programa em **C#** que usa um botão para executar um comando no CMD.
Esse comando serve para pegar um banco de Dados num servidor e colocar na máquina em um caminho que você escolher(*MySQLDump*).

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string caminhoArq = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string nomesever = (string)sever.Text;
    string nomeuser = (string)user.Text;
    string senha = (string)pass.Text;
    string NumeroPorta = (string)porta.Text;
    string banco = (string)comboBox1.Text;
    string caminhoDoArquivo = (string)caminho.Text;
    string data = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

    try  //Faz Backup
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/C \"" + caminhoArq + @"\FuncoesMySQL\mysqldump -u" + nomeuser + " -p" + senha + " -h" + nomesever + " -P" + NumeroPorta + " " + banco + " >  " + caminhoDoArquivo + @"\" + banco + data + ".sql");
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Erro ao Executar o Comando!");
    }
    MessageBox.Show("backup feito");

}
```

Uso algumas variáveis do tipo char para reitirar os parâmetros da tela e executar o **CMD**.
E isso funciona perfeitamente!!
Mas, quando o nome do usuário te um **espaço**, ou até mesmo o caminho onde vai ser colocado o arquivo tiver algum **espaço ou acentuação**, ele não executa o comando no **CMD**.

**Preciso saber como fazer esse comando executar no CMD corretamente, mesmo com esses desafios da acentuação.**

Exemplo de comando correto:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/C \"D:\FuncoesMySQL\mysqldump -uroot -p1234 -hservidor -P3305 bancoteste >  C:\bancoteste18-02-2019.sql");
```

Comment: Coloque um exemplo de como deve ficar a chamada, por favor

Comment: De maneira geral quase sempre é suficiente colocar trechos de código que contém espaço entre aspas, para não ocasionar erros. Você já tentou essa possibilidade?

Comment: como faria isso nesse comando?

Answer (score 0):

Isso ocorre quando há espaços ou caracteres especiais pois o espaço cria uma separação nos parâmetros do CMD. Ex.:

```
cmd.exe /C D:\FuncoesMySQL\mysqldump -uroot ...
```

É interpretado sendo:

- **cmd.exe**: Programa que será executado
- **/C**: Primeiro parâmetro
- **D:\FuncoesMySQL\mysqldump**: Segundo parâmetro
- **-uroot**: Terceiro parâmetro
- ... e por aí vai

Com o espaço (no exemplo, digamos que a pasta é "Funcoes MySQL"), ele considera:

```
cmd.exe /C D:\Funcoes MySQL\mysqldump -uroot ...
```

É interpretado sendo:

- **cmd.exe**: Programa que será executado
- **/C**: Primeiro parâmetro
- **D:\Funcoes**: Segundo parâmetro
- **MySQL\mysqldump**: Segundo parâmetro
- **-uroot**: Quarto parâmetro
- ... e por aí vai

Logo ele não vai interpretar os parâmetros de forma correta resultando no erro.

Para prevenir isso, basta passar o caminho entre apas duplas (""), que será interpretado todo conteúdo como um único parâmetro, ex:

```
cmd.exe /C "D:\Funcoes MySQL\mysqldump" -uroot ...
```